# Using AppleScript to run a script command specifically in a Rosetta terminal (currently getting execution error on "do script")

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line

I have a scenario where I'd like to use AppleScript from the command line (I'm currently doing this from iTerm) to launch a Rosetta-based terminal and run a command in that terminal (while leaving the terminal open and showing output in that new terminal).

I have used the common strategy of duplicating my /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app to a second /Applications/Utilities/Terminal-Rosetta.app with the "Open using Rosetta" flag set (e.g. described in https://www.courier.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-to-setup-your-apple-m1-for-development/).

To test with a normal terminal, I can run this command:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell app "Terminal-Rosetta" to do script "echo hello"'`

This launches a new Terminal window and then runs "echo hello" successfully in the new window.

However, if I attempt to do the same thing with my Rosetta terminal like this:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal-Rosetta" to activate' -e 'tell app "Terminal-Rosetta" to do script "echo hello"'`

The `activate` command succeeds (i.e. a new Rosetta terminal window pops up), but then the `echo hello` command fails with this error:

`71:93: execution error: Terminal-Rosetta got an error: "echo hello" doesn’t understand the “do script” message. (-1708)`

Is there a way to make this work?  Or is there something with the syntax that needs to change when using a Rosetta-based Terminal?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: It has been a long day for me and maybe I'm just tired, but what exactly is the difference between your first and your second osascript example?

Comment: Having said that: Did you try running `arch -arch x86_64 /path/to/binary` in an ARM Terminal to force the binary to run with Rosetta?

Comment: @nohillside The only difference is that the second one ran with a Terminal app (a duplicate of the built-in terminal app) that has the "Open Using Rosetta" box checked (if the options if you right click and do "Get Info").

Comment: I have not.  I was trying to convince myself that `arch` would be a reliable way of doing it.

Comment: Both code samples do `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal-Rosetta" to ...`...

Comment: And that would be a typo that I need to go fix now...Thank you.